# JavaScript: Delete only the selected user input and not the entire HTML block

Tags: javascript, html

I am having problems trying to figure out how to delete one specific user input instead of the entire HTML block. I am aware that the delete button fires on the HTML ID 'noteDelete' which is the parent of each user input, however I'm not sure how to set a specific ID for each user input. If that is the solution. For each user input would a new ID have to be created in order for the delete button to fire on each input? Here's the code:

```js
//Event Targets
let titleArea = document.getElementById('title')
let noteArea = document.getElementById('note')
let submitNoteButton = document.getElementById('addNote')
let noteSum = document.getElementById('noteValue')
//let noteDeleteButton = document.querySelectorAll('noteDelete')
//let deleteNoteButton = document.getElementById('noteDelete')
let viewNoteButton = document.getElementById('viewNote')



//Event Handlers
submitNoteButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  let listTitle = title.value
  let noteInput = noteArea.value
  let listNote = document.createElement('div')
  let noteDelete = document.createElement('button')
  noteDelete.innerHTML = 'Delete'
  noteDelete.setAttribute('id', 'noteDelete')
  //listNote.classList.add('listNote')
  if (listTitle) {
    listNote.innerHTML =
      `<h3>${listTitle}</h3>
        <p>${noteInput}</p>
        <button type="button" id="deleteNote" form="delete">Delete</button>
        <button type="button" id="viewNote" form="view">View</button>`
  }
  noteSum.appendChild(listNote)
  noteSum.appendChild(noteDelete)
  noteArea.value = ""
  titleArea.value = ""

  let deleteNoteButton = document.getElementById('noteDelete')
  deleteNoteButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    let deleteValue = document.querySelector('noteDelete')
    deleteValue.remove()
  })

})
```

```html
<body>
  <section class="inputField">
    <h1>Note Taker</h1>
    <h3>Add A New Note:</h3>
    <form id="inputText">
      <div>
        <label for="title">Title:</label>
        <input type="text" name="title" id="title">
      </div>

      <div>
        <label for="note">Note:</label>
        <textarea id="note" name="note" rows="2" cols="100"></textarea>
      </div>
    </form>
    <button type="button" id="addNote" form="note">Add Note</button>
  </section>
  <section class="outputField">
    <form id="outputValue">
      <div id="noteValue">
        <!--<h3>Title</h3>
                <p>I would like to buy a AMMMBURGER!</p>
                <button type="button" id="deleteNote" form="delete">Delete</button>
                <button type="button" id="viewNote" form="view">View</button>-->
      </div>
    </form>
  </section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use IDs at all. You can benefit from the `Event` parameter of triggering an `EventListener` to identify which note you're modifying. Specifically, since you're essentially deleting the `div` that is the direct parent of the delete `button` the user is clicking, you can identify that element using `e.currentTarget.parentNode.remove();`.

This will guarantee that only the note you are clicking gets deleted without affecting the rest or worrying about finding the correct `id`.

It's also worth mentioning that no two elements should ever have the same `id`, so in situations where you might want to delete/query multiple elements, it's better to use a class like @ismail suggested in his answer.

working snippet:

```js
//Event Targets
let titleArea = document.getElementById('title');
let noteArea = document.getElementById('note');
let submitNoteButton = document.getElementById('addNote');
let noteSum = document.getElementById('noteValue');
let viewNoteButton = document.getElementById('viewNote');

//Event Handlers
submitNoteButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  let listTitle = title.value;
  let noteInput = noteArea.value;
  let listNote = document.createElement('div');

  let noteDelete = document.createElement('button');
  noteDelete.innerHTML = 'Delete';

  if (listTitle) {
    listNote.innerHTML =
      `<h3>${listTitle}</h3>
            <p>${noteInput}</p>
            <button type="button" form="view">View</button>`
  }

  noteSum.appendChild(listNote);

  noteArea.value = "";
  titleArea.value = "";

  noteDelete.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    e.target.parentNode.remove();
  });
  listNote.appendChild(noteDelete);
})
```

```html
<body>
  <section class="inputField">
    <h1>Note Taker</h1>
    <h3>Add A New Note:</h3>
    <form id="inputText">
      <div>
        <label for="title">Title:</label>
        <input type="text" name="title" id="title">
      </div>

      <div>
        <label for="note">Note:</label>
        <textarea id="note" name="note" rows="2" cols="100"></textarea>
      </div>
    </form>
    <button type="button" id="addNote" form="note">Add Note</button>
  </section>
  <section class="outputField">
    <form id="outputValue">
      <div id="noteValue">
      </div>
    </form>
  </section>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

So the problem you are having is that you will be having multiple notes, each having its own delete button. First, don't use an Id on the button because every time a note is added, two or more buttons will have the same Id. Instead, you can use a class on the delete button, for example, `<button class="delete-note-btn>delete note</button>` Then you can use **event delegation** to target a parent element (or so) that exists in the HTML file. something like this.

```
const notesList = document.querySelector(".note-list") // The container element where your notes will be stored.

notesList.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    if (e.target.classList.contains('delete-note-btn') { // the element clicked is the delete note button
    // Delete the specific note
    // assuming the note is the delete button's parent element then we can select it like this
    let note = e.target.parentElement
    // remove (delete) the note
    note.remove()  
}
})
```

Hope it helps.